# What is the issue with this longitude/latitude bounding box algorithm for geolocation searching?

Tags: javascript, typescript, math, geolocation, calculation

I have a small bit of code I'm using to find a bounding box for a location in order to search user profiles within a radius. It is working almost as I want, but unfortunately the final values are a bit distorted. For instance, if I pass 50 miles into the function, I'm getting points that are maybe 70 miles from the origin instead of 50. I think it has to do with one of the constants I'm calculating being off slightly.

Constants:

```
const RAD_CON = Math.PI / 180; // Radian conversion constant
const R_EARTH = 6378; // Radius of the earth in Km
const KM_PER_MILE = 1.609344; // Km/mile conversion constant

// I think this might be wrong
const METER_DEGREES = (1 / ((2 * Math.PI / 360) * R_EARTH)) / 1000; // Meters per degree lat/lng
```

The offending code:

```
_getBoundingCoords(location: Location, miles: number) {
    const meters = miles * KM_PER_MILE * 1000;

    const latNorth = location.lat + (meters * METER_DEGREES);
    const latSouth = location.lat - (meters * METER_DEGREES);
    const lngWest = location.lng + (meters * METER_DEGREES) / Math.cos(location.lat * RAD_CON);
    const lngEast = location.lng - (meters * METER_DEGREES) / Math.cos(location.lat * RAD_CON);

    return [latNorth, latSouth, lngWest, lngEast];
}
```

In case you are wondering how I'm using this, I am using the returned values to build a query for a mongodb collection. The data been queried is in the format

```
{
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}
```

The query:

```
const query = {
  $and: [{
    'location.lat': {
      $lte: latNorth,
      $gte: latSouth,
    },
  }, {
    'location.lng': {
      $lte: lngWest,
      $gte: lngEast,
    },
  }],
};
```

Comment: Hi Ty, did u finish the solution with better accuracy ? Or did you swap your approach with libraries mentioned ? I need calculation for 10 km max, so it can be enough in my case, Im just still not sure I understand how to add bearing into your code and from where to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ***lot*** of math associated with calculating latitude and longitude coordinates, with very detailed explanations at...

- https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.

Fortunately, you do not have to translate this to Javascript, because there is a great resource that implements these "geodesy functions" at...

- https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy
- https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geodesy-library.html

To help get you started using these functions, here's a quick sample using some of the functions to...

- calculate the distance between two coordinates, and
- calculate a coordinate given a starting coordinate, bearing, and distance (in meters).  (The values used in this example were taken from the first reference above in the section titled "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point".)

```html
<script type="module">

  import LatLon, { Dms } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/geodesy@latest/latlon-spherical.min.js';
  
  Dms.separator = '';
  // Calculate distance between two points.
  let d = new LatLon( 52.205, 0.119 ).distanceTo( new LatLon( 48.857, 2.351 ) );
  console.log( d );
  
  // Calculate destination point given starting point, distance and bearing.
  let p1 = new LatLon( Dms.parse( "053°19′14″" ), Dms.parse( "-001°43′47″" ) );
  let brng = Dms.parse( "096°01′18″" );
  let dist = 124.8 * 1000;  // Distance in meters.
  let p2 = p1.destinationPoint( dist, brng ); // 53°11′18″N, 000°08′00″E
  console.log( p2 );
  console.log( [ Dms.toDms( p2.lat, 'dms' ), Dms.toDms( p2.lon, 'dms' ) ] );
  
</script>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Looking to do the calculations myself, but this is a good option if I don't end up happy with my own thing.

Comment: Not sure why I received a double ding on this answer.  @Ty_, am adding another answer that leverages the function in the first reference, so that there's not a requirement to import an entire library.

Answer (score 2):

While you would be best, as Jon Trent suggested, to use a geodetic library, a quick hack might improve the code you have.

This is to use the fact that a degree of longitude, at a given latitude, is worth, as a distance, cos(latitude) as much as is a degree of latitude. So at the equator they are about the same, but as you approach the poles a degree of longitude gets to be a smaller and smaller distance.

If your bounding boxes are quite small (a few miles say) you would get reasonable accuracy by using the cosine of the latitude at the middle as a scale factor.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing...

- https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

...in particular the Javascript code under section **Destination point given distance and bearing from start point**, the following is the formula for calculating the destination point given the latitude, longitude, bearing, distance, and radius of earth.  Note that angles are in radians, and the distances are in whatever units desired (ie, miles, km, meters, etc).

Additionally there are two helper functions that I created to convert Degrees, Minutes, and Seconds to radians, and vice versa.  Probably not the best interface, but they are functional.

```js
//
// Convert degrees, minutes, and seconds to radians.
//
function dmsToRad( deg, min, sec ) {
  return Math.sign( deg ) * ( Math.abs( deg ) + min / 60 + sec / 3600 ) * Math.PI / 180;
}

//
// Convert radians to degrees, minutes, and seconds.  Rounds to 1/3600th.
//
function radToDms( rad ) {
  let d = Math.round( Math.abs( rad ) * 180 / Math.PI * 3600 ) / 3600;
  let deg = Math.trunc( d );
  let remainder = ( d - deg ) * 60;
  let min = Math.trunc( remainder );
  remainder = ( remainder - min ) * 60;
  let sec = Math.round( remainder );
  
  deg = deg * Math.sign( rad );
  return {
    degrees: deg, minutes: min, seconds: sec,
    pretty: `${(Math.sign(rad)===-1?'-':'')+('00'+Math.abs(deg)).slice(-3)}°${('0'+min).slice(-2)}′${('0'+sec).slice(-2)}″`
  };
}

// Calculate the destination point given the latitude, longitude, bearing,
// distance, and radius of earth.  Note that angles are in radians, and
// the distances are in whatever units desired (ie, miles, km, meters, etc).
//
// Sourced directly from https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
//
function destinationPoint( φ1, λ1, brng, d, R ) {
  const φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin( φ1 ) * Math.cos( d / R ) +
             Math.cos( φ1 ) * Math.sin( d / R ) * Math.cos( brng ) );
  const λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2( Math.sin( brng )*Math.sin( d / R ) * Math.cos( φ1 ),
             Math.cos( d / R ) - Math.sin( φ1 ) * Math.sin( φ2 ) );
  return { lat: φ2, lon: λ2 };
}

//
// Test using the sample data from the reference web site.
//
let dest = destinationPoint( dmsToRad( 53, 19, 14 ), dmsToRad( -1, 43, 47 ), dmsToRad( 96, 1, 18 ), 124.8, 6371 );
console.log( dest )
console.log( [ radToDms( dest.lat ), radToDms( dest.lon ) ] ); // 053°11′18″ 000°08′00″
```

Note that the bearing is clockwise with North being 0°.  These functions will not only allow you to calculate the destination at due N, E, S, & W, but also add intermediate points, if for instance, you wish to show a more circular bounding range.

Comment: I'm going to go with that library you mentioned haha. Looks very easy to use. The above looks a little deeper than I'm looking to get into. 

Thanks for everything!

Comment: @Ty_ no worries.  Glad I was able to assist.  Plus I find it kinda amusing that the response with a useful rating of -1 was selected as the answer...